# Riverpod - widget stays in loading state when listening to a streamProvider

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-streambuilder

I can't seem to get my `ref.watch(mapProvider).when(` to build the data case of my widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      AndroidGoogleMapsFlutter.useAndroidViewSurface = true;
    }
    _vm = ref.watch(findPageVm);
    _widgetRef = ref;
    final isStillLoading = useState(true);

    return ref.watch(findStoreProvider).when(
        data: (store) {
          _store = store;
          store.$search();
          return Stack(children: [
            const VpLoadingPage(
              noText: true,
            ),
            AnimatedOpacity(
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                opacity: isStillLoading.value ? 0 : 1.0,
                duration: GOOGLE_MAP_OVERLAY_DURATION,
                child: Stack(children: [
                  ref.watch(mapProvider).when(
                      data: (snapshot) {
                        return GoogleMap(
                          markers: snapshot.markers,
                          myLocationEnabled: true,
                          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(_store!.userPosition.latitude,
                                _store!.userPosition.longitude),
                            zoom: snapshot.zoom,
                          ),
                          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                            _vm.controller.complete(controller);

                            Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 550),
                                () => isStillLoading.value = false);
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(error.toString()),
                      loading: () {
                        return const VpLoadingPage(noText: true);
                      }),
                  mapOverlay()
                ]))
          ]);
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) => Text(error.toString()),
        loading: () => const VpLoadingPage(noText: true));
  }
```

provider:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/application/local/map_data/map.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/domain/vegan_item_establishment/_common/vegan_item_establishment.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/pages/find/search_results_provider.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/stores/store.dart';
import 'package:vepo/src/presentation/stores/user_store.dart';

final findStoreProvider = FutureProvider((ref) async {
  final userStore = await ref.watch(userStoreProvider.future);
  final store = FindStore(ref, userStore: userStore);
  await store.$search();
  return store;
});

final mapProvider = StreamProvider<VpMap>((ref) async* {
  final store = await ref.watch(findStoreProvider.future);
  store.map$!.listen((event) {
    inspect(event);
  });
  store.mapController$.add(VpMap.empty());
  yield* store.map$!;
});

class FindStore extends Store {
  factory FindStore(Ref $provider, {required UserStore userStore}) {
    instance = FindStore._internal($provider, userStore);
    instance.map$ = instance.mapController$.stream;
    instance._userStore = userStore;
    return instance;
  }

  FindStore._internal(this.$provider, this._userStore);

  static late FindStore instance;

  final Ref $provider;
  Stream<VpMap>? map$;
  VpMap? map;
  late final StreamController<VpMap> mapController$ =
      StreamController.broadcast();
  late UserStore _userStore;
  Set<Marker> markers = <Marker>{};
  Stream<String?>? searchTerm;

  Position get userPosition => _userStore.userPosition;

  Future<List<VgnItmEst>> _$search(String searchTerm) async {
    final result =
        await $provider.watch(searchResultsProvider(searchTerm).future);
    return result;
  }

  Set<Marker> _fromSearchResults(List<VgnItmEst> searchResults) {
    return searchResults
        .map((searchResult) => Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(searchResult.id.toString()),
            position: LatLng(searchResult.establishment!.location!.lat,
                searchResult.establishment!.location!.lng)))
        .toSet();
  }

  Future<FindStore> $search([String searchTerm = '']) async {
    final searchResults = await _$search(searchTerm);
    markers = _fromSearchResults(searchResults);
    map = VpMap(position: _userStore.userPosition, markers: markers);
    mapController$.add(map!);
    return this;
  }
}
```

I've been trying to make `FindStore` a singleton as I thought it would be due to getting a different `FindStore` but it did not fix it. I have inspected the values being emitted with `store.map$!.listen((event) {` and there is one value emitted. Why does the widget remain in the loading state when reading `mapProvider`?